# Adding extra conditional to a sidenote command

Tags: conditionals, key-value, marginnote

Below is an adapted part of the code from the `sidenotes` package, which I intend to include in my class file. I'm trying to extend it with an optional argument `[flip]`, with usage `\sidenote[flip]{Text}` to flip the text to the margin, opposite to the margin it is in currently. 
If no argument is given, e.g. `\sidenote{Text}`, the text is typeset normally, with as its only conditional the current value determined by the `ifoddpage` package.

I tried several approaches, but the existing `sidenotes` package simply causes confusion for me... I don't know where the argument of `\isempty` is going. The following lines are an example of what I'm referring to:

```
\newcommand{\sidenote}[2][]{%
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
{\sidenotemark%
\sidenotetext{#2}}%
{\sidenotemark[#1]%
\sidenotetext[#1]{#2}}%
}
```

I made a slightly different, probably less general version of the code (see below) and I'm trying to implement the feature described above, but the optional argument seems to be ignored.

So how can I implement this feature in my command?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{keyval}

% define conditional and key
\makeatletter
\newif\ifflip\flipfalse
\define@key{sidenotes}{flip}[true]{\csname flip#1\endcsname}
\setkeys{sidenotes}{flip=false}
\makeatother

% counters, skips, etc.
%\newdimen\sidenoteskip \sidenoteskip=.1pt
\newcounter{sidenote} %
\setcounter{sidenote}{1} %

%main command
\newcommand{\sidenote}[2][]{%
  %\nobreak\hspace{\sidenoteskip}\nobreak
  \textsuperscript{\thesidenote}
  \addtocounter{sidenote}{-1}
  \sidenotetext{#2}
}

% command to typeset text
\newcommand{\sidenotetext}[2][]{%
\addtocounter{sidenote}{1}
\checkoddpage%
  \ifoddpage%
    \begingroup%
      \setkeys{sidenotes}{#1}%
      \ifflip%
        \marginnote[\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}#2]{}%
      \else%
        \marginnote{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}#2}%
      \fi%
    \endgroup%
  \else%
    \begingroup%
      \setkeys{sidenotes}{#1}%
      \ifflip%
        \marginnote{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}#2}%
      \else%
        \marginnote[\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}#2]{}%
      \fi%
    \endgroup%
  \fi%
\addtocounter{sidenote}{1}%
\ignorespaces
}%

\begin{document}
%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\sidenote{stuff} consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.\sidenote{stuff} Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes\sidenote{stuff}, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\sidenote{stuff} consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.\sidenote{stuff} Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes\sidenote{stuff}, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\sidenote[flip]{stuff} consectetuer adipiscing elit. %side note not flipped
Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.\sidenote{stuff} Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes\sidenote{stuff}, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your `\sidenote` command is defined to have an optional argument, but does nothing with it: I see nowhere `#1` in the replacement text for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code.

First: you define `\sidenote` with an optional argument, but do nothing with it.

Second: you don't understand clearly what the optional argument to `\marginnnote` does. What you have to do is to locally enable `\reversemarginpar`, not to use the optional argument to `\marginnote`.

Here's a working version.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{keyval}

% define conditional and key
\makeatletter
\newif\ifflip
\define@key{sidenotes}{flip}[true]{\csname flip#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

% counters, skips, etc.
%\newdimen\sidenoteskip \sidenoteskip=.1pt
\newcounter{sidenote}

%main command
\newcommand{\sidenote}[2][]{%
  %\nobreak\hspace{\sidenoteskip}%
  \refstepcounter{sidenote}%
  \textsuperscript{\thesidenote}%
  \begingroup
  \setkeys{sidenotes}{#1}%
  \ifflip
    \reversemarginpar
    \marginnote{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}#2}%
  \else
    \marginnote{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}#2}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\sidenote{stuff} consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo 
ligula eget dolor.\sidenote[flip]{stuff} Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis 
dis parturient montes\sidenote{stuff}, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies 
nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede 

\clearpage

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\sidenote{stuff} consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo 
ligula eget dolor.\sidenote[flip]{stuff} Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis 
dis parturient montes\sidenote{stuff}, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies 
nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede 

\end{document}
```

(Left is page 1, with the normal side notes at the right margin and the flipped one at the left; right is page 2, with the reverse behavior.)

[image]